# Why are decisions "made" instead of "done"?

Tags: verbs

Typically when we've decided something, we say we've "made a decision". But why is a decision associated with the verb "to make"? Nothing is being made. If anything, it seems a decision should be "done", and associated with the verb "to do".

Why do we make them instead of doing them? Or deciding them?

Comment: While English has a make/do distinction some languages obviously don't, suggesting a certain degree of conceptual similarity. This may be a sort of liminal case. The metaphor of construction makes sense to me; it's hard for me to think about what we're "doing" while deciding if not "making" something. We also use a spatial metaphor, saying that someone has "come to" or "arrived at" a decision. Possibly meaning a person's mental energies have converged at a point of decision within their own brain, but also allowing that a person's decision overlaps with some external standard.

Comment: Yes, comparatively more often we are doing decisions, than rarely making or taking decisions. Whenever we decide, we do decide. If you check the graph for make/take decision and decide in Ngram viewer, you can see that  we are almost only doing decisions.

Comment: Decisions are *taken*. In 1944 someone took a decision to say "made" instead and it stuck until 1953. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decision+taken%2Cdecision+made&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdecision%20taken%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecision%20made%3B%2Cc0

Comment: There are several other things we sometimes make rather than do:  : announcements, bookings, agreements, proposals, remarks, nuisances, commotions, insinuations etc .

Comment: @Kris - Your ngram link clearly shows that making decisions has always been more popular than taking them. Here's "make decision" vs "take decision" that shows the same trend: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+decision%2Cmake+decision&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20decision%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20decision%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Kris and rianjs: [This](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decision+taken%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cdecision+made%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+decision+taken%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cdecision+made%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdecision%20taken%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecision%20made%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecision%20taken%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecision%20made%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) ngram suggests that *taken* is mainly a BrE thing, and even then it is used only about the same as *made*.

Answer (score 1):

For me it has more to do with intent vs action. A decision is made but that does not mean that the deed will be done. A decision is a thought process, not a physical action, and it comes before the action is completed. The verb "to do," implies an action with a result or, conjugated, describes an attribute.